# openssl set password for private key in command line

Tags: linux, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt some data via openssl tool, and the question is how can I set password for private.key in this command:

```
openssl smime -sign -signer /var/www/protected/keys/ym.pem -inkey /var/www/protected/keys/ym.key -nochain -nocerts -outform PEM -nodetach
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who faces with the same problem:
Remove a passphrase from a private key this way:

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.pem -out newPrivateKey.pem
```